# Mailslurper connection timeout after 6 seconds

Tags: ubuntu, telnet

I'm trying to setup mailslurper for email testing but I keep getting a connection timeout after 6 seconds whether using telnet or netcat.

I have left the config as default and mailserver creates the database on startup.

connecting with telnet

```
$ telnet localhost 2500
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 Welcome to MailSlurper!
221 Bye
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

The mailslurper console gives this:

```
MailSlurper: INFO - 2016/03/11 22:24:06 libmailslurper: INFO - Worker 2 queued to handle connection from 127.0.0.1:41756
MailSlurper: INFO - 2016/03/11 22:24:06 libmailslurper: INFO - Reading data from client connection...
MailSlurper: INFO - 2016/03/11 22:24:12 libmailslurper: INFO - Connection timeout. Terminating client connection
```

I have also written a script to send an email but the mail is not saved or recorded in the log so not seen.

Comment: What is the problem you are having?

Comment: I can't send an email to mailslurper. It just disconnects on timeout.

Comment: OK, why is it taking you more than six seconds to start sending it data?

Comment: I'm not, if I connect by telnet i can't type "ehlo localhost" before it disconnects so I found a script to send a mail here but it has the same result. http://giantdorks.org/alain/smtp-test-message-via-shell-script-using-netcat-instead-of-telnet/

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately, I could not send email via telnet or netcat. The source code contains send-mail-test.py and load.sh to run it.This loads test data into the database.